# Почему код вылетает с ошибкой IllegalStateException?

Tags: java, android, android-camera

Пробую работать с Camera2API по вот такому примеру http://goo.gl/OZoaAK и вот такая проблема :

**пишу такой код**

```
public class CameraHelper {
private CameraCaptureSession mSession = null;
private CameraManager mCameraManager = null;
private CameraDevice mCameraDevice = null;
private String mCameraID = null;
private Context context;
private TextureView mTextureView;
private ImageReader mImageReaderYUV;
private Handler handler;
private static ByteArrayOutputStream outputStream;


public CameraHelper(@NonNull CameraManager cameraManager, @NonNull String cameraID, Context context) {
    mCameraManager = cameraManager;
    mCameraID = cameraID;
    this.context = context;

    //нужно разобраться с этой строчкой, она 650 в коде
    handler = new Handler();
}

public static ByteArrayOutputStream getOutputStream() {
    return outputStream;
}

public void viewFormatSize(int formatSize) {

//      Получения характеристик камеры, Для получения характеристик необходимо
//      использовать метод getCameraCharacteristics(String cameraId). Этот метод возвращает объект
//      класса CameraCharacteristics, в котором сконцентрированы параметры по камере. В данном классе
//      сконцентрировано огромное количество параметров
    CameraCharacteristics cc;
    try {
        cc = mCameraManager.getCameraCharacteristics(mCameraID);

        // Получения списка выходного формата, который поддерживает камера
        StreamConfigurationMap configurationMap =
                cc.get(CameraCharacteristics.SCALER_STREAM_CONFIGURATION_MAP);

        // Получения списка разрешений которые поддерживаются для формата jpeg
        Size[] sizesJPEG = new Size[0];
        if (configurationMap != null) {
            sizesJPEG = configurationMap.getOutputSizes(ImageFormat.JPEG);
        }

        if (sizesJPEG != null) {
            for (Size item : sizesJPEG) {
                System.out.println("w:" + item.getWidth() + " h:" + item.getHeight());
            }
        } else {
            Log.e(MainActivity.LOG_TAG, "camera with id: " + mCameraID + " don`t support format: " +
                    formatSize);
        }

    } catch (CameraAccessException e) {
        Log.e(MainActivity.LOG_TAG, e.getMessage());
    }
}

public boolean isOpen() {
    return mCameraDevice != null;
}


//    В методе openCamera() с помощью нашего менеджера открываем камеры. В параметрах метода
//    указываем, какую камеру открывать, а также обработчик, который будет отслеживать состояния
//    открытия камеры.
public void openCamera() {
    try {
//            я так понимаю что здесь мы проверяем прописан ли у нас доступ к камере в манифесте и
//            если все в порядке то выполняется открытие камеры
        if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(context, Manifest.permission.CAMERA) !=
                PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
            return;
        }
        mCameraManager.openCamera(mCameraID, mCameraCallback, null);
    } catch (CameraAccessException e) {
        Log.e(MainActivity.LOG_TAG, e.getMessage());
    }
}

public void closeCamera() {

    if (mCameraDevice != null) {
        mCameraDevice.close();
        mCameraDevice = null;
    }
}

private CameraDevice.StateCallback mCameraCallback = new CameraDevice.StateCallback() {

    @Override
    public void onOpened(@NonNull CameraDevice camera) {
        mCameraDevice = camera;
        createCameraPreviewSession();
        MainActivity.ToastPrint(mCameraDevice.getId());
    }

    @Override
    public void onDisconnected(@NonNull CameraDevice camera) {
        mCameraDevice.close();
        Log.i(MainActivity.LOG_TAG, "disconnect camera  with id:" + mCameraDevice.getId());
        mCameraDevice = null;
    }

    @Override
    public void onError(@NonNull CameraDevice camera, int error) {
        Log.i(MainActivity.LOG_TAG, "error! camera id:" + camera.getId() + " error:" + error);
    }
};

private void createCameraPreviewSession() {
    SurfaceTexture texture = mTextureView.getSurfaceTexture();
    texture.setDefaultBufferSize(640, 480);
//        Surface surface = new Surface(texture);

//        для получения изображения нам необходимо использовать  ImageReader. Для получения
//        максимально возможной скорости передачи кадров нам необходимо использовать «сырой формат». То
//        есть, jpeg нам не подойдет, поскольку он будет давать задержку на время конвертации кадра и
//        таким образом у нас возникнет очень низкий fps. Для получения максимальной продуктивности
//        следует использовать ImageFormat.YUV_420_888.
    mImageReaderYUV = ImageReader.newInstance(640, 480, ImageFormat.YUV_420_888, 1);

    try {
        final CaptureRequest.Builder builder =
                mCameraDevice.createCaptureRequest(CameraDevice.TEMPLATE_PREVIEW);

        builder.addTarget(mImageReaderYUV.getSurface());
//            builder.addTarget(surface);

        mCameraDevice.createCaptureSession(
                Collections.singletonList(mImageReaderYUV.getSurface()),
//                    Collections.singletonList(surface),
                new CameraCaptureSession.StateCallback() {

                    @Override
                    public void onConfigured(@NonNull CameraCaptureSession session) {
                        mSession = session;
                        try {
                            mSession.setRepeatingRequest(builder.build(), null, null);
                        } catch (CameraAccessException e) {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onConfigureFailed(@NonNull CameraCaptureSession session) {
                    }
                },
                null
        );

        mImageReaderYUV.setOnImageAvailableListener(onImageAvailableListener, handler);

    } catch (CameraAccessException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}


private final ImageReader.OnImageAvailableListener onImageAvailableListener =
        new ImageReader.OnImageAvailableListener() {
            @Override
            public void onImageAvailable(ImageReader reader) {
                final Image image = reader.acquireLatestImage();

                if (image == null) return;

                outputStream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
//эту строчку нужно будет расскоментировать
//                    BufferedOutputStream v = new BufferedOutputStream(outputStream);

                ByteBuffer bufferY = image.getPlanes()[0].getBuffer();
                byte[] data0 = new byte[bufferY.remaining()];
                bufferY.get(data0);
                ByteBuffer bufferU = image.getPlanes()[1].getBuffer();
                byte[] data1 = new byte[bufferU.remaining()];
                bufferU.get(data1);
                ByteBuffer bufferV = image.getPlanes()[2].getBuffer();
                byte[] data2 = new byte[bufferV.remaining()];
                bufferV.get(data2);

                try {
                    outputStream.write(data0);
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
                for (int i = 0; i < data1.length; i++) {
                    outputStream.write(data1[i]);
                    outputStream.write(data2[i]);
                }

                handler.post(new ImageSaver(context));
            }
        };

private static class ImageSaver implements Runnable {
    private BufferedOutputStream bos;
    private Context context;

    public ImageSaver(Context context) {
        this.context = context;
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {

        final File pictureFile = getOutputMediaFile();
        if (pictureFile == null) {
            return;
        }
        try {
            bos = new BufferedOutputStream(
                    new FileOutputStream(pictureFile));
            bos.write(convertOutputToByteArray(getOutputStream()));
            bos.flush();

            Toast.makeText(context, "Picture saved: " + pictureFile.getName(),
                    Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } finally {
            try {
                bos.close();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }

    }

    private byte[] convertOutputToByteArray(ByteArrayOutputStream stream) {
        return stream.toByteArray();
    }

    private static File getOutputMediaFile() {
        File mediaStorageDir = new File("/sdcard/", "JCG Camera");

        if (!mediaStorageDir.exists()) {
            if (!mediaStorageDir.mkdirs()) {
                return null;
            }
        }

        String timeStamp = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMMdd_HHmmss").format(new Date());
        File mediaFile = new File(mediaStorageDir.getPath() + File.separator + "IMG_" +
                timeStamp + ".png");

        return mediaFile;
    }
}

public void setTextureView(TextureView mImageView) {
    mTextureView = mImageView;
}
```

**Вот такая ошибка**

```
  FATAL EXCEPTION: main
  Process: com.example.aleksey.camera2api, PID: 15845
  java.lang.IllegalStateException: maxImages (1) has already been acquired, call #close before acquiring more.
  at android.media.ImageReader.acquireNextImage(ImageReader.java:352)
  at android.media.ImageReader.acquireLatestImage(ImageReader.java:248)
  at com.example.aleksey.camera2api.CameraHelper$3.onImageAvailable(CameraHelper.java:199)
```

Что я делаю не так?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

В стектрейсе четко указывает на ошибку:

```
maxImages (1) has already been acquired, call #close before acquiring more.
```

После использования нужно закрывать `image` в `onImageAvailableListener`